# Browser mode to be set using Jquery or C#

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Whenever i open my website it opens in Browser Mode : IE8 Compatibility View. I don't want my website to open in compatibility view either 8 or 9.
I need to set a Browser Mode of IE using jquery or C#. Document Mode of IE had been set but Browser mode of IE could not be set using jquery or C#.

I don't want Browser Mode of IE to be set manually.

Please help me to resolve this problem..
Thanking You in advance.

Comment: Maybe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx could help you

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can set the Browser Mode - that's up to the user.

You can define your document mode by providing your own `x-ua-compatible` instruction:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Further: [Defining Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Actually this is used to set the Document Mode i need to Set Browser Mode

Comment: @user1423848 I don't believe you can instruct the browser which mode it should use. The browser mode determines the ua-string and so much more. It isn't something you can set programmatically.

Comment: You cannot set the browser mode.

Comment: No other solution to set the Browser Mode.

Comment: @user1423848 The Browser Mode is something for the *user*, not something for the *Developer*. You wouldn't want webpages being able to control your Browser Mode.